# Evaluate a expression defined in a string

Tags: r

I'm trying to evaluate a formula, e.g., `"x+y"` which stored in a string. However, I need to substitute `x` and `y` with values from my environment (I uses ranges here for simplicity).

```
eval(substitute(x+y,list(x=1:10,y=101:110)))
 [1] 102 104 106 108 110 112 114 116 118 120
```

I was assuming that I could use parse to generate the formula then from the string.

```
eval(substitute(parse(x+y),list(x=1:10,y=101:110)))
```

However, this "obviously" gives only

```
expression(x+y)
```

So i tried to trick the expression into substitute using it twice. However, this also does not give the expected results. Any suggestions?

```
>substitute(substitute(expr,list(x=1:10,y=101:110)),list(expr=parse(text="x+y")))
substitute(expression(x + y), list(x = 1:10, y = 101:110))
> eval(substitute(substitute(expr,list(x=1:10,y=101:110)),list(expr=parse(text="x+y"))))
expression(x+y)
> eval(eval(substitute(substitute(expr,list(x=1:10,y=101:110)),list(expr=parse(text="x+y")))))
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'x' not found
```

Comment: `f <- "x+y"; eval(parse(text = f), list(x=1:10, y=101:110))`? Of course, "If the answer is parse() you should usually rethink the question." ([fortune 106](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fortunes/vignettes/fortunes.pdf))

Comment: Of course. Why didn't come up with that idea myself. Thanks. (if you paste as answer I will accept it.